# AutoHotKey: Calling one script from another script

Tags: scripting, include, autohotkey

I just discovered AutoHotKey and it seems like a dream come true. I have two .ahk scripts, `A.ahk` and `B.ahk`. I want to call script B from within script A.

The AHK forums are strangely silent on the subject but I am sure this is possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the #Include directive you are looking for. You include ScriptB.ahk, then call its functions like you normally would.

```
#include SomeFile.ahk
```

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm

Comment: You're welcome. As a side note, I think the barrier for AHK is much higher than it needs to be because though they are thorough, the documentation and forums are a mess. It's very difficult to find help on anything but the basics. They would benefit greatly from a StackOverflow format.

Answer (score 6):

Using an #include directive is more common, but occasionally you will need to call an external AHK script. This is easily accomplished using the [Run or RunWait](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) commands. While you can [pass arguments](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#cmd) to the called script through the command line you cannot call functions within it directly. Also, this approach will create a separate thread for the called script, but that may be the point.

Answer (score 2):

What really helped was a combination of the previous answers and a little bit of outside knowledge. I needed a script that would call more than 1 script, and since my files were in different folders, I found that I needed to specify the entire path of the files (I am sure this could be shortened but this was good enough for me at this point). I also didn't want all the different scripts that were being called to appear in the tray of the taskbar so I added an ExitApp statement at the end.
So my 'generalized' code was follows. Hopefully it can help another person.

````
#SingleInstance, Force

; HotKeys
#Include C:\Users\username\path1\Arrows.ahk
#Include C:\Users\username\path1\HomeEndModifiers.ahk

; SoundKeys
#Include C:\Users\username\path2\VolumeAdjustment.ahk

; Opening Programs
#Include C:\Users\username\path3\OpeningPrograms.ahk

ExitApp
```
````

Comment: not sure this script will do that much. Include does not run the ahk file

Comment: It does run on my machine. Please explain.